# «Год на раздумья или раздумье?» Или все равно?

Tags: выбор-слов

«Год на раздумья или раздумье?» Или все равно?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, оба варианта корректны. Частотность в Нацкорпусе 167:67 в пользу ед. ч.